# Entity framework context is not refreshing on modification

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, entity-framework, entity

I have a `WPF` Project which is `n-tier` architecture and  **I use context per/call** as it has `Direct-database` and `web-service`

*Sorry a bit long question*

> Presentation => Business Layer => Data Layer

In `datalayer` i have `UnitOfWork` pattern implemented.

> Initally when my `DefaultAccessPoint` was a `Static` property i had issues on `multiple thread` using the same  context.
>
> I had resolved it by changing the `DefaultAccessPoint` to a `non-static` property, and seems that multi thread issue had been Resolved .
>
> after the fix =>(e.g) User could insert data into the Application on First tab(which takes approx. 3 mins) and simultaneously access the Second Tab(To fetch some data) while both are done in separate threads.

**But after this Fix the `Context` doesn't refresh when a modification is done**

The initial fix was done under `DataProviderBase` class were i changed `static` DataAccessPoint to `Non-static` and commented those lines that you see below.

How would i keep the context refresh with multi threading ?

Any Help is appreciated

**Code Block**

**This is my `dataproviderbase`class every data-provider is inherited this base**

```
public abstract class DataProviderBase
{
    public DataProviderBase()
    {
        DefaultAccessPoint = new DataAccessAccessPoint(ConnectionString);
    }

    protected readonly ILogger logger = LoggerFactory.GetLogger();
    private static string _connectionString;
    public static string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return _connectionString;
        }
        set
        {
            _connectionString = value;
            //COMMENTED as Fix for multiThreading
            //_defaultAccessPoint = new DataAccessAccessPoint(ConnectionString);
        }
    }

    private IDataAccessAccessPoint _defaultAccessPoint;
    public IDataAccessAccessPoint DefaultAccessPoint
    {
        get
        {
             //COMMENTED as Fix for multi Threading
            // Removed statis Default AccessPoint that was causing the issue
            return _defaultAccessPoint; //?? (_defaultAccessPoint = new DataAccessAccessPoint(ConnectionString));
        }
        set { _defaultAccessPoint = value; }
    }


}
```

This is my `DataAccessPoint`

```
public class DataAccessAccessPoint : IDataAccessAccessPoint
{
    private string _connectionString;

    public string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return _connectionString;
        }
        set
        {
            _connectionString = value;
        }
    }

    private IDataContext context;

    public DataAccessAccessPoint(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
        context = new MyDataContext(_connectionString);
    }

    public virtual bool Save()
    {
        return context.SaveChanges() > 0;
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    //Here i supply the context to my Data access layers
    private IMyDataLayerDA _myDA;
    public IMyDataLayerdDA MydDA
    {
        get { return _myDA ?? (_myDA = new MydDA(context)); }
        set { _myDA = value; }
    }
   
}
```

My `DataProvider`

```
 public class PersonRoleDataProvider : DataProviderBase, IPersonRoleDataProvider
{
    public MYDTOCLASS AuthenticateUser(string userId)
    {
        return DefaultAccessPoint.MydDA.AuthenticateUser(userId);
    }

    public IEnumerable<MYDTOCLASS> GetRoles(int personId)
    {
        return DefaultAccessPoint.MydDA.GetRoles(personId);
    } 
}
```

**DataProviderAccessPoint**

```
  public class DataProviderAccessPoint
  {

    private static PersonRoleDataProvider _personRoleDataProvider;
    public static PersonRoleDataProvider  PersonRoleDataProvider 
    {
        get
        {
             if(_personRoleDataProvider==null)
             _personRoleDataProvider = new PersonRoleDataProvider();

            return _personRoleDataProvider;
        }
    }
   
 }
```

Comment: So where/how do you instantiate `DefaultAccessPoint` now? Note that `PersonRoleDataProvider` is probably a singleton anyway.

Comment: @GertArnold `DefaultAccessPoint` is initialized in the constructor of `DataProviderBase` and `PersonRoleDataProvider` is derived from base